# The multi-part identifier could not be bound SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The select query gives an error:

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.HD_Caller_Info.ci_name" could not be bound
>
> The multi-part identifier "dbo.HD_Caller_Info.ci_caller_no" could not
> be bound

This is the part of query that gives the error above

```
ISNULL(dbo.HD_Caller_Info.ci_name, '-') AS callerName, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Caller_Info.ci_caller_no, '-') AS callerPhone,
```

My full query

```
SELECT      dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_log_no AS logNo, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_customer_rptno, '-') AS custReportNo, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_customer_id, '-') AS customerID, 
                             ISNULL(dbo.HD_Customer_Master.cu_customer_Shortname, '-') AS shortName, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Customer_Master.cu_customer_Name, '-') AS longName, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_branch_code, '-') AS branchCode, 
                             ISNULL(dbo.HD_Customer_Branch.cb_branch_Name, '-') AS branchName, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Caller_Info.ci_name, '-') AS callerName, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Caller_Info.ci_caller_no, '-') AS callerPhone, 
                             ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_create_date, 101), '-') AS cmDateCreate, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_create_date, 103), '-') AS dateReport, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, 
                             dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_create_date, 108), '-') AS timeReport, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_close_datetm, 103), '-') AS dateClose, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, 
                             dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_close_datetm, 108), '-') AS timeClose, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_severity, '-') AS severity, ISNULL(SUBSTRING(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_category, 1, 2), '-') AS prCode, 
                             ISNULL(SUBSTRING(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_category, 0, 6), '-') AS prCodelvl2, ISNULL(dbo.refMainCategory.Ct_Abbreviation, '-') AS prCategory, dbo.refCategory.Ct_Description AS category, 
                             ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_description, '-') AS cmDescription, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_reso_datetm, 103), '-') AS dateCreate, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, 
                             dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_reso_datetm, 108), '-') AS timeCreate, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_end_date, 103), '-') AS dateEnd, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_end_date, 
                             108), '-') AS timeEnd, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_create_id, '-') AS createdBy, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Person_Info.pi_name, '-') AS staffIncharge, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_vendor_id, '-') AS vendor, 
                             ISNULL(dbo.refAction.ac_abbreviation, '-') AS action, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_status, '-') AS statusCode, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_resolution, '-') AS resolutionDesc, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), 
                             dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_due_datetm, 103), '-') AS dueDate, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_due_datetm, 108), '-') AS dueTime, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101), '-') AS getToday, 
                             ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE() + 2, 101), '-') AS getDateBreach, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE() - 1, 103), '-') AS getDate, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(WEEK, - 1, GETDATE()), 103), '-') AS getWeek, 
                             ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(MONTH, - 1, GETDATE()), 103), '-') AS getMonth, ISNULL(dbo.refCase_Status.cs_case_sts_desc, '-') AS statusDesc, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(dd, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_create_date, 
                             GETDATE()), '-') AS aging, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(hh, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_create_date, GETDATE()), '-') AS aging_hour, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_create_date, GETDATE()), '-') AS aging_minute, 
                             ISNULL(CONVERT(int, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_downtime), '-') AS breachPeriod, CONVERT(int, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_disclaimer) AS tbpsDisclaimer, dbo.HD_SLA.sl_sla_code, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_sla_code, 
                             dbo.HD_SLA.sl_due_date_timeframe AS problemTimeFrame, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_rectype AS recType, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_create_date AS cmCreateDate, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_status AS status, 
                             dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_due_datetm AS cmDueDate, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_close_datetm AS cmCloseDate, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_resolve_datetm AS cmResolveDate, 
                             dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_reso_datetm AS resoDateTime, dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_end_date AS crEndDateTime, ISNULL(REPLACE(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_category, '-', ''), '-') AS catCode, 
                             dbo.HD_Customer_Branch.cb_state AS cbState, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_create_id AS cmCreateId, dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_action AS crAction, dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_create_id AS crCreateId, 
                             ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_vendor_id, '-') AS cmVendorId, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_asset_sn AS cmAssetSn, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_mode, '-') AS cmMode, dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_fwd_to AS cmFwdTo, 
                             ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_group_id, '-') AS cmGroupId, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_jpn_problem_type, '-') AS cmJpnProblemType, DATEDIFF(minute,
                                 (SELECT        MIN(cr_reso_datetm) AS Expr1
                                   FROM            dbo.HD_Case_Resolution
                                   WHERE        (cr_log_no = dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_log_no) AND (cr_action = '08')),
                                 (SELECT        MIN(cr_reso_datetm) AS Expr1
                                   FROM            dbo.HD_Case_Resolution
                                   WHERE        (cr_log_no = dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_log_no) AND (cr_action = '101'))) AS workaroundbreach, DATEDIFF(minute,
                                 (SELECT        MIN(cr_reso_datetm) AS Expr1
                                   FROM            dbo.HD_Case_Resolution
                                   WHERE        (cr_log_no = dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_log_no) AND (cr_action = '08')),
                                 (SELECT        MIN(cr_reso_datetm) AS Expr1
                                   FROM            dbo.HD_Case_Resolution
                                   WHERE        (cr_log_no = dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_log_no) AND (cr_action = '03'))) AS responsetimebreach, dbo.HD_RelCategory_Group.rcg_check_group AS rcgCheckGroup
    FROM            dbo.HD_Case_Master INNER JOIN
                             dbo.HD_Case_Resolution ON dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_log_no = dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_log_no LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.HD_Customer_Master ON dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_customer_id = dbo.HD_Customer_Master.cu_customer_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.HD_Customer_Branch ON dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_branch_code = dbo.HD_Customer_Branch.cb_branchcode AND dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_customer_id = dbo.HD_Customer_Branch.cb_customer_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.refState ON dbo.HD_Customer_Branch.cb_state = dbo.refState.st_state_code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.refCategory ON dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_category = dbo.refCategory.Ct_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.refCase_Status ON dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_status = dbo.refCase_Status.cs_case_sts_code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.refAction ON dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_action = dbo.refAction.ac_code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.HD_Person_Info ON dbo.HD_Case_Resolution.cr_fwd_to = dbo.HD_Person_Info.pi_person_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.refMainCategory ON SUBSTRING(dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_category, 1, 2) = dbo.refMainCategory.Ct_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.HD_SLA ON dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_sla_code = dbo.HD_SLA.sl_sla_code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             dbo.HD_RelCategory_Group ON dbo.HD_Case_Master.cm_log_no = dbo.HD_RelCategory_Group.rcg_log_no
```

What I have tried is I put from after as 'columnname' like:

```
 ISNULL(dbo.HD_Caller_Info.ci_name, '-') AS callerName from
 HD_Caller_Info, ISNULL(dbo.HD_Caller_Info.ci_caller_no, '-') AS
 callerPhone from HD_Caller_Info,
```

Comment: You've failed to reference the `HD_Caller_info` table in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: I highly recommend learning to use table aliases in your queries. Aliases will make them much more readable and make these kind of mistakes less likely.

Comment: @DaleK if i use aliases i need to change all the query

Comment: Yes, but it will be worth it for future maintenance - regardless its a tip for the future if you don't use it now.

Comment: FYI, using 3 part naming for column names to due to be deprecated and removed from SQL Server. Alias your tables and then qualify the columns with that alias. It also makes your code *way* more succinct and therefore far easier to read. I also really suggest better use of white space, and line breaks.

Comment: @Dale K thank u i will modify and post the solution if done